# Value Control extensions not display in LightSwitch HTML Application Screen Designer

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Value Control extensions are not displayed in LightSwitch HTML Application Screen Designer. I have refered the below link for creating value control extension.

1. I have added the created extension to the LightSwitch HTML Application but not display.
2. How to add the value control extension controls to lightswitch HTML Application..?